Use of simple present tense verb form with the word 'none'
What verb form should we use when we are using the word 'none'in sentence?
An example:

None of the instruments depicted in these sculptures precisely resembles the sitar.

or

None of the instruments depicted in these sculptures precisely resemble the sitar.

